# How to delete data from a specific index in elasticsearch after a certain period?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-curator

I have an index in elasticsearch with is occupied by some *json* files with respected to *timestamp*.
I want to delete data from that index.

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index_name
```

Above code deletes the whole index. My requirement is to delete certain data after a time period(for example after 1 week). Could I automate the deletion process?

I tried to delete by using [curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/index.html).

But I think it deletes the indexes created by `timestamp`, not data with in an index. Can we use curator for delete data within an index?

It will be pleasure if I get to know that either of following would work:

- Can Curl Automate to delete data from an index after a period?
- Can curator Automate to delete data from an index after a period?
- Is there any other way like python scripting to do the job?

References are taken from the official site of [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you use dates in your indexes name definition?

Comment: @MichaelDz No I have a single index and I am keeping my json logs there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DELETE BY QUERY` API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Basically it will delete all the documents matching the provided query:

```
POST twitter/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

But the suggested way is to implement indexes for different periods (days for example) and use `curator` to drop them periodically, based on the `age`:

```
...
logs_2019.03.11
logs_2019.03.12
logs_2019.03.13
logs_2019.03.14
```

Comment: I have only one index and I am storing my _json_ data into it.If I made indices according to the date,then how can I group them all in to a single index pattern, so that I can search a particular data in **Kibana** ?

Comment: Suppose, now I have index named **animals** and I am inserting data in to it, then I can create an index pattern named **animals** and can search on it.But what will be the index pattern if I am using the _date_ as the index name? Then I may need to create _n number of index patterns_ with respected to index names right?

Comment: Adarsh, you can use aliases to group indices together. Index patterns can use wildcards, e.g. `animals-*`, to accommodate dated indices.

Comment: @untergeek , I got your valuable point and it make sense.If my index is like 

**animals-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}**

For sure I can make index patterns like _animals-*_
But the doubt is that, can I use curator to delete these indices with respect to old date?
The following link is one I found on web that curator command,and i don't know whether it is correct or not.
Attaching the part which I think is correct.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-indices-older-than-30-days/96630/5

What should be the timestring for delete if my index is someting like 

**animals-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}**

Comment: You can define the pattern as you want, just do some tests and see. :)
We are doing like that!

Comment: It works exactly like that, Adarsh. Curator's original use case was deleting indices by date stamp. It uses a different syntax, e.g. `%Y.%m.%d` for what in Logstash looks like `%{+YYYY.MM.dd}`, but the functionality is there.

Comment: @Enrichman , I did some tests and reached a point where I could create multiple indices like you suggested.Now my index is like, for example , **logstash-2019.03.21**
So I am going to use curator like u said.I referred some of the documents and reached a point  that


`- filtertype: pattern
 kind: prefix
 value: logstash-`


can be used to select indices starting with **logstash-**
But how can I append the _timestamp_ with it , and check whether it is older than 7 days from current timestamp?

Comment: @untergeek , Since I am newbie to this technology, I went through the documentation on Curator on the following link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/filtertype_pattern.html#_prefix

Now my doubt is that how can I search for the indices older than 7 days from today, if my indices is like 
**logstash-2019.03.10**,
**logstash-2019.03.15**,
**logstash-2019.03.16**

and how to use timestring in curator.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/filtertype_pattern.html#_timestring

Comment: Guys I was wrong that Indices are deleting by their name concatenated with timestamp.So I think how to Split the timestamp and check whether it is older than 7 days from current.Actually I think Curator can delete indices with respect to the time they created.Thank you all for valuable information.Now it seems fine with Curator.

Comment: @Enrichman, Thanks for the Help.Now I can delete indices older than 7 days using curator.
I referred the following link for more knowledge on this topic.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/indices-deleting-using-curator-different-retention-period-for-different-index/77792

Can we automate the curator for deletion purpose?Now I need to run curator every day.
Any reference on automating this tool,so that it will delete automatically the older data?

Comment: @ADARSHK we used Jenkins to automate this, but a simple cronjon will work. :) Glad you made it!

Answer (score 4):

Simple example using [Delete By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html):

```
POST index_name/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "lte": "2019-06-01 00:00:00.0",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will delete records which have a field "timestamp" which is the date/time (within the record) at which they occured.  One can run the query to get a count for what will be deleted.

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query: {
-- as above --
```

Also it is nice to use offset dates

```
         "lte": "now-30d",
```

which would delete all records older than 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can always delete single [documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/document.html) by using the [HTTP request method DELETE](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/delete-doc.html).

To know which are the id's you want to delete you need to query your data. Probably by using a range filter/query on your timestamp.

As you are interacting with the REST api you can do this with python or any other language. There is also a Java client if you prefer a more direct api.

Comment: If I am using timestamp as the filter, how can I implement the idea to delete documents in last 7 days?
Pleasure if you have any reference about the task.


`{
  "found" :    true,
  "_index" :   "website",
  "_type" :    "blog",
  "_id" :      "123",
  "_version" : 3
}`


This is the code snippet from the link you given.If I am checking with the documents with timestamp older then I given, then how should be my request in above code?

Can I automate this process with Python script or something?

Comment: No, that's the response of the given example DELETE request. Have a look at the [range query on dates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) and make sure you have a date to use it on. Then use that with _delete_by_query as suggested above.